# Inmobi API for Javascript based mobile App

Tags: javascript, ads, nokia-wrt

Has Inmobi provided API for Javascript based Mobile Application? I am writing Symbian apps using WRT (Web Runtime Widget). These apps are purely written in Javascript. Currently I am unable to find support for such apps from Inmobi. I have to integrate Inmobi ads in those apps. Is there any hack/solution available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not have the Javascript based integration yet but we will be releasing it within the next 2-3 weeks. In it is possible for you, you can, in the meantime, make a call to your own server where you can integrate with InMobi via our Ad request API. Please e-mail us at helpdesk@inmobi.com and we will help you with your preferred form of integration.

(Full Disclosure: I work for the Global Operations team at InMobi)